# Using a DropDownList SelectedItem.Text is not working in server side

Tags: c#, asp.net

I just want to set the the DDL selected text from server side

```
ddlCurrency.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(dTableAttendeeCurrency.Rows[0]["Currency_Id"] );
```

But this is not working

Comment: NOt working means what? What is the error/ exception? were the result are unexpected?

Comment: You've mentioned `SelectedItem` in the title but your code has `SelectedValue`?

Comment: Check whether ddl datasource is having  Convert.ToString(dTableAttendeeCurrency.Rows[0]["Currency_Id"]  value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to set true to "Selected" property as follows.

```
ddlCurrency.Items.FindByValue(Convert.ToString(dTableAttendeeCurrency.Rows[0]["Currency_Id"])).Selected = true;
```